# Upgrading Ember Web Application from 1.2.2

Tags: javascript, ember.js, upgrade, updates

The Ember web application currently in our production environment has the following versions.

- ember.js - 1.2.2
- ember.data - 0.13

I've found upgrade notes from ember 1.10 onwards in the following guide but the version of ember in our application is much older.

Guide: https://www.emberscreencasts.com/meta_guide_to_upgrading_ember

Ideally, the application needs to be upgraded to 1.10 then following this guide to 1.13 and then progressing upwards to 2.0+ etc.

Are there any known issues with upgrading the application from a low version of 1.2.2 to 1.10. Ember-data will need to be upgraded in parallel, I assume but not too sure on when to upgrade each.

Finally, is there any possible way to add the ember-cli into an already existing application? If so, what ember-cli version should be added and when, to upgrade with ember.js and ember-data.js.

Answer (score 5):

I've done such a update a few months ago and here some notes:

First since you are on `1.x` I think you should directly jump to `1.13`. This should only break if you use private APIs. Then fix your deprecations and try to jump to the latest `2.x`.

However there should be mentioned that this is a huge jump. The philosophies have changed in so many ways. Probably you use a lot of `{{render}}`, not much components, and so on in your existing app.

I personally would recommend you to start from a fresh `ember-cli` application and then try to integrate your existing code part by part.

Start with the router and the data layer. Then start migrating route by route, always with it's controller and template. If something breaks, fix it. Start with routes with less code and dependencies first.

A jump to `ember-cli` always means that you have to change every single file since probably you don't use ES6 modules yet. If you do so its much easier to always have a running application and migrate file by file, instead of trying to migrate the hole beast at once. This also gives you a good opportunity to migrate pre `2.x` code to the latest recommend way to do things.

Comment: Not to mention the enormous changes of the Ember Data API from 0.13 to 1.0

Comment: yeah! If you try to jump in steps you end up changing a lot of code multiple times.

Comment: We do use ember-data-tastypie-adapter as we have a Django backend.

Answer (score 2):

Preferred migration path,

1.12 -> 1.13 -> 2.0 -> 2.1 -> 2.4 - > 2.7

For fixing deprecations follow this link,

http://emberjs.com/deprecations/v1.x/   (this contains all 1.x series deprecation and warning)
http://emberjs.com/deprecations/v2.x/  (this contains all 2.x series deprecation and warning)